# array.push create multiple occurence

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hi guys I have a problem with my javascript/html code

in HTML body I have 3 `<button class='color'>` with 3 different value, the first is red, second green and third white.

if I click on first button(red), the value red is added 1 time to color_filter, if I click on second button(green) the value green is added 2 times, and if I click on third button(white) the value white is added 3 times.

I would like to know how to prevent this, I want that click on each button add only 1 time it's value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var color_filter = [];
var width_filter = [];

filter_data();

function filter_data(value) {
 
  $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
  var action = 'fetch_data';
  var colore = get_filter('colore', value);
  var larghezza = get_filter('larghezza', value);
  $.ajax({
    url:"fetch_data.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      action: action,
      colore: colore,
      larghezza: larghezza
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.filter_data').html(data);
    }
  });
}

function get_filter(class_name, value) {

  if (class_name == 'colore') {
    filter = color_filter;
  } else if (class_name == 'larghezza'){
    filter = width_filter;
  }
  if (class_name != undefined && value != undefined){
    if (document.getElementById(value).src.includes("add.svg")) {
      filter.push(value);
      document.getElementById(value).src = "images/icons/delete.svg"; //after adding the filter change the image, then a new click on same button will remove the filter
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < filter.length; i++) {
        if (filter[i] == value) {
          filter.splice(i, 1);
          break
        }
      }
      document.getElementById(value).src = "images/icons/add.svg";
    }
    return filter;
  }

}

$('.filtro').click(function (event) {
  const value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('value');
  filter_data(value);
});



  });
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="filter color" value="red"><img id = 'red' src="images/icons/add.svg">red</button>
  <button class="filter color" value="green"><img id = 'green' src="images/icons/add.svg">green</button>
  <button class="filter color" value="white"><img id = 'white' src="images/icons/add.svg">white</button>

<button class="filter larghezza" value="1.5"><img id = '1.5' src="images/icons/add.svg">1.5</button>
  <button class="filter larghezza" value="2"><img id = '2' src="images/icons/add.svg">2</button>
  <button class="filter larghezza" value="3"><img id = '3' src="images/icons/add.svg">3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Why _describe_ your HTML code instead of posting it? `<button>` has no `value`, it has a text. Also, `filter_data()` is undefined

Comment: Would you pleae post a whole code which also runs in any environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is everytime you click on a button you are adding one more event listener for the class `color`. So, first of all remove the

```
$('.'+class_name).click(function() {
      filter.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Instead, you should write just this,

```
function get_filter(class_name)
{
  if (class_name == 'color'){
      filter = color_filter;
  }else{
      filter = width_filter;

  filter.push(yourColorValue);
  return filter;
}
```

Besides where are you calling the `get_filter` method?

In the onClick handler you can get the cliked color value, if there is a child parent relation from filter_data() to get_filter() method you can pass the color via the filter_data method,

```
$('.color').click(function(event){
  const value = $(event.currentTarget).attr('value');
  filter_data(value);
});
```

And then in the filter_data(value) method,

```
function filter_data(value) {
    $('.filter_data').html('<div id="loading" style="" ></div>');
    var action = 'fetch_data1';
    var colors = get_filter('color', value);

    $.ajax({
      url: "fetch_data1.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: {
        action: action,
        colors: colors
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.filter1_data').html(data);
      }
    });
  }

function get_filter(class_name, value)
{
      if (class_name == 'color'){
          filter = color_filter;
      }else{
          filter = width_filter;
    
      filter.push(value);
      return filter;
    }
```

Comment: I call get_filter from another function that use Ajax to POST data. With your solution how can I get colorValue from the value of button clicked

Comment: Exactly that is my point, without knowing how you are calling  the get_filter method it is impossible for us to tell.

Comment: oh ok, I assign get_filter to a var, var colors = get_filter(classname) where classname is a string

Comment: I think you should update the post with whole code. Otherwise we are unable to help.

Comment: sorry, there is a problem, when I add: var width = get_filter('width', value);   and width: width to the Ajax post data, when I click on a button the value is added either on color_filter and width_filter array, do you know what can cause the issue?

Comment: I've updated the code, now all button add to the same array, the color_filter array whichever button I click. If I delete one get_filter call it works perfectly

Comment: All the button has className color. That is why it is being added in the color_filter. If you want to add them in the width_filter you need to have some button with className `larghezza`

Comment: yes I've forget to update the button in the code above, naturally they have two class, larghezza and colore, but the problem still occur

Comment: I solved the issue, instead of use two array I use one object with two properties, thank you so much, without your help I could not have solved precedent issues

Comment: Great to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably cleaner ways to implement the behaviour you seek, but a workaround to avoid adding a `click` handler every time you run the function would be :

```
$('.' + class_name).off("click").click(....)
```

This way, you remove any previous click handler, and you add just one.

Comment: yes, I have already use this solution and it works perfectly, but I'm looking for a cleaner ways

Comment: ... uh, no you're not. Your question says exactly : `the value white is added 3 times. 
I would like to know how to prevent this` and I answered exactly the problem as it was written. You never said `It's added one time as expected, and I'm looking for cleaner ways to do this`